# cakephp select multiple only passing first value

Tags: php, cakephp, select

I have generated a form, a number of the fields are multiple selects. The values are generated from a foreach (due to the required format):

```
echo '<select name="data[formdata]['.$question['PrPageQuestion']['ID'].']" id="formdata'.$question['PrPageQuestion']['ID'].'" multiple="multiple">';
foreach($contacts as $contact):
    echo '<option value="'.$contact['PrDataContact']['ID'].'">'.$contact['PrDataContact']['Name'].' ('.$contact['PrDataContact']['Email'].')</option>';
endforeach;
echo '</select>';
```

However when i select multiple and submit the form, i run the debug only one value is being passed, not a string as expected.

The html output is:

```
<select name="data[formdata][2]" id="formdata2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="13">A Contact (a.contact@email.com)</option>
    <option value="14">A. Nother-Contact (a.n.contact@email.com)</option>
    <option value="15">A. New. Contact (anc@email.com)</option>
    <option value="17">New Conti (new@conti.com)</option>
</select>
```

The output of var_dump is:

```
array(2) { 
    ["_method"]=> string(4) 
    "POST" ["data"]=> array(1) { 
        ["formdata"]=> array(8) { 
        //other data was here
        [1]=> string(1) "1" 
        [2]=> string(2) "15" 
        [3]=> string(1) "4" 
        [4]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Which bit of html did you mean?

Comment: The output of the created select, and can we have a var_dump of the $_POST too, after you selected multiple items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [ ] after the name to tell html that this is an array of values to be submitted

```
echo '<select name="data[formdata]['.$question['PrPageQuestion']['ID'].'][]" id="formdata'.$question['PrPageQuestion']['ID'].'" multiple="multiple">';
foreach($contacts as $contact):
    echo '<option value="'.$contact['PrDataContact']['ID'].'">'.$contact['PrDataContact'['Name'].' ('.$contact['PrDataContact']['Email'].')</option>';
endforeach;
echo '</select>';
```

You should then get:

```
array(2) { 
    ["_method"]=> string(4) 
    "POST" ["data"]=> array(1) { 
        ["formdata"]=> array(8) { 
        //other data was here
        [1]=> string(1) "1" 
        [2]=> array(2) {
           [0]=>string(2) "15"
           [1]=>string(2) "17"
        },
        [3]=> string(1) "4" 
        [4]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Strangely i have used it without the [] before and it gave results like 1,2,3,4. However this worked just as well so thank you.